# Python - does not define init function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysvn

I am getting this error while trying to work with **pysvn**:

```
/usr/bin/python /Users/keith/Dev/Python/svntool.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/keith/Dev/Python/svntool.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pysvn   File "/Users/keith/pysvn/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    import pysvn._pysvn_3_3 ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_pysvn_3_3)

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

import pysvn


def get_books(srcUrl, tgtPath):
    client = pysvn.Client()
    client.checkout(srcUrl, tgtPath)


def set_login(setCache=True, setInteractive=True, uid='', pwd=''):
    client = pysvn.Client()
    client.set_auth_cache(setCache)
    client.set_interactive(setInteractive)
    client.set_default_username(uid)
    client.set_default_password(pwd)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_login(True, True, '******', '******')
    #write_temp()
    get_books('https://free2.projectlocker.com/******/svn/MyProject/', './examples/pysvn')
```

Take into account I started learning Python yesterday.  Never looked at it before that.  :)

My google-fu is failing me and I am not finding anything on SO either.  Any ideas on:

1. What does this error mean?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: Where/how did you get/build your pysvn library?  Google seems to indicate that this was likely to do with improper compilation of the module or mismatched names somewhere

Comment: Downloaded from the PYSVN site, packaged and ready for install.  http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html

Comment: are you linux or mac?

Comment: Mac.  Also brand new to the Mac world.  lol  Been on Winers since 1.0 - back in the 90s.

Comment: Wondering if I am setup correctly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227818/import-error-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-init-mysql-import